# Comparing total sum of column with a column from another table that has nested select query in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Greetings programmers,

I'm using **PDO** for my php filing 
so my code's idea is a validation that the total sum of points doesn't exceed an identified maximum points number from another table
that's how it looks:

```
if($res1 = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT sum(POINT_NO) as total_point FROM new_order WHERE EMP_ID = ?')) {
$res1->bind_param('i', $_POST['ID']);
$res1->execute();
$res1->store_result(); 
$sum_point = 0;
while($row1 = $res1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$sum_point += $row1['total_point'];
}
$max_point = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT MAX_POINT FROM max_point
                            WHERE ENT_ID = (SELECT ENTITY_ID FROM employee WHERE EMP_ID = ?) ');
$max_point ->bind_param('i', $_POST['ID']);
$max_point ->execute();     
$max_point->store_result();         
if($sum_point > $max_point){
    $message = "error .\\n try again.";
   die("<script type='text/javascript'>
 window.location.href='user_new_order.php';
 alert('$message');</script>");
}
}else{
    $max_point bind_param('i', $_POST['point_no']);
    $max_point->execute();
}
```

I know my coding might be not written so well because I'm new to php and I really need a help from experts.
I appreciate your well of help and thank you in advance.

Comment: What, exactly, are you wanting to do? What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: the output must be passing the value of the points that doesn't exceed the max_points that was defined in another table if it is less or equal the value. otherwise, return the same posted value if there is no limit assigned.